# How to scope/limit the effect of Enter-VsDevShell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I am scripting the build of a third-party piece of software, which also is the reason why I need to accommodate its needs. The third-party software expects `nmake` to be available along with compiler, linker, librarian and other tools found in the MSVC toolchain.

So I thought I'd use `Enter-VsDevShell` from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell` and be done with it. Here's my minimal script to show the issue:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

function Get-VSBasePath
{
    Param($vsrange = "[16.0,18.0)")
    $vswhere = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
    $vspath = & $vswhere -products "*" -format value -property installationPath -latest -version "$vsrange"
    return $vspath
}

function Do-Stuff
{
    Param($arch = "x64")
    $vspath = Get-VSBasePath
    if (-not (Get-Command Enter-VsDevShell -CommandType Cmdlet -ErrorAction silentlycontinue))
    {
        Import-Module "$vspath\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll" -Force|Out-Host
    }
    Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath "$vspath" -DevCmdArguments "-arch=$arch -no_logo" -SkipAutomaticLocation|Out-Host
}

echo "Do we know cl.exe now? (#1)"
Get-Command cl -CommandType Application -ErrorAction silentlycontinue|Out-Host
echo "Calling Do-Stuff"
Do-Stuff
echo "Do we know cl.exe now? (#2)"
Get-Command cl -CommandType Application -ErrorAction silentlycontinue|Out-Host
```

After the `Import-Module` I can see there is no counterpart cmdlet to `Enter-VsDevShell` in that module:

```
$ Get-Command -Module Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Enter-VsDevShell                                   17.0.0.0   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell
Cmdlet          Send-VsDevShellTelemetry                           17.0.0.0   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell
```

Issuing a `Remove-Module Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell` also doesn't undo the effect of `Enter-VsDevShell`, unfortunately. My guess is that for the most part it affects environment variables. It even leaks its effect into the calling PowerShell.

So how can I limit the effect of `Enter-VsDevShell` to only the `Do-Stuff` function, say?

---

I need to run several builds back to back in order to build for all my desired target platforms. And that's why I want to limit the effect of `Enter-VsDevShell`.

I have also tried issuing another `Enter-VsDevShell` with a different target platform, but it doesn't work reliably.

Comment: `Start-Job` should be isolated from this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the hint. I'll read up on it. Never worked with that before.

Comment: @JeroenMostert feel free to write it up as an answer. Otherwise I might eventually do that. Using `Start-Job` is a bit finicky, since it also means different semantics when it comes to accessing the output or "error information" in general, but my small scale tests showed it's feasible.

Comment: It depends on what your `Do Stuff`is actually supposed to do, but it looks to me, that you should be able to get away with a: `Enter-VsDevShell -SkipExistingEnvironmentVariables ...` and/or spawning a (pwsh) subshell.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. This sounds like a very interesting hint. Haven't tried it yet, but will tomorrow. Where did you find out about this command line argument, though? Thanks, @not2qubit.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Source: Google, reading the PS1 comandlets used by (RE) the DLL and reading the help page: `help Enter-VsDevShell`. :D